# Discord.js awaitReactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return (
    ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣", "5️⃣", "6️⃣"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
    user.id === msg.author.id
  );
};

message
  .awaitReactions({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"] })
  .then(async function (collected) {
    const reaction = collected.first();

    console.log(reaction.emoji.name);

    if (reaction.emoji.name === "1️⃣") {
      message.delete();

      msg.reply("Done");
    }
  })
  .catch((collected) => {
    message.delete();
    msg.reply("No response given.");
  });
```

My Code Above is not working and never firing, I do not know why I looked up on google and they all give out this code. Any Help is Appreciated thanks.

Comment: What is your Discord.js version?

Comment: ^13.3.1 is my discord version

Comment: Do you have `GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS` intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to use the GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS intent. My Bad.